# Data is displayed in Classic view but not in console view

Tags: apex, visualforce, console, custom-console-components

I have a VF page where on click of a button, it makes a GET call and fetches data from external system and displays it in another VF page. This works fine in classic. But when I do the same in Sales Console, response is Null. Data is not displayed in VF Page. Can any one please tell me is there anything specific we need to include in the code to get this working in both the views.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using lightning console?

Comment: @Sanket kumar -  No. the Sales Console available in Classic